# How to load php file for specific page in admin?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, wp-admin

Hello and thanks for the guidance!

Trying to load a custom .php file for only my home page (template is **page-home.php**) by using this code:

```
add_action('admin_init','load_home_meta');
function load_home_meta() {
  global $pagenow, $post;
  if ($pagenow=='edit.php' && '104' == $post->ID) {
        include 'metaboxes/home-meta.php';
  }
}
```

The page's unique ID is *104*. I need this to work only on the home page since the nonce checks in the php file are breaking the ability to save other pages that don't use these custom meta fields.

Thanks!

### Try Two:

Tried this:

```
add_action('admin_init','load_home_meta');
function load_home_meta() {
    // Get the Post ID
    if( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    elseif( isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ) $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
    if( !isset( $post_id ) ) return;
 
    // Get the Page Template
    $template_file = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
    if($template_file == 'page-main-home.php'){
     include '/metaboxes/home-main-home.php';
    }
}
```

And seems to be partially working since I'm getting this error on the edit page in the admin section:

> Warning: include(/metaboxes/home-main-home.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/metaboxes/home-main-home.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.3.15/share/pear')

Why would the include work with the simple: `include 'metaboxes/home-main-home.php';` ?

I'm also tried the above code with a starting slash and without, both generating the missing/unable to find the file error.

---

### Try Three:

Fixed my template typo error and am no longer not getting to the file with this:

```
add_action('admin_init','load_home_meta');
function load_home_meta() {
    // Get the Post ID
    if( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    elseif( isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ) $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
    if( !isset( $post_id ) ) return;
 
    // Get the Page Template
    $template_file = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
    if($template_file == 'page-main-home.php'){
     include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/metaboxes/home-meta.php');
    }
}
```

But now in each meta-box I'm getting these errors:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /nfs/c07/h04/mnt/111667/domains/staging.[site_name].org/html/wp-content/themes/[theme_name]/metaboxes/home-meta.php on line 184

But when I comment that out and just do a simple:

```
include 'metaboxes/home-meta.php';
```

The backend page renders fine... I'm lost as to what I'm doing incorrectly.

---

### Try Four:

So, all the above still don't work.

Again, I'm trying to:

1. Hide the editor on a specific page in the admin backend
2. Include custom-fields using metaboxes for only the home (front) page.
3. Only serve the home-meta.php file to the front page and no other pages/posts.

`functions.php`:

```
    /**
     * Hide Editor
     * @author Bill Erickson
     * @link http://www.billerickson.net/code/hide-editor-on-specific-page-template/
     */
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_editor' );
    
    function hide_editor() {
        // Get the Post ID
        if( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) $post_id = $_GET['post'];
        elseif( isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ) $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
        if( !isset( $post_id ) ) return;
     
        // Get the Page Template
        $template_file = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
        if($template_file == 'front-page.php'){
          remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
           
            // add custom .js to footer for uploading images
                function custom_admin_js() {
                $url = get_option('siteurl');
                $url = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/library/js/libs/meta-content.js';
                echo '"<script type="text/javascript" src="'. $url . '"></script>"';
                }
                add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js');
                
    //          include 'metaboxes/home-meta.php';
    
        }
    }
    
    // Loading Home Page Meta Box Code from External .php file
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page','load_home_meta' );
    function load_home_meta() {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
            include( get_template_directory_uri() . '/metaboxes/home-main-home.php' );
        }
    }
```

I changed my previous home template file to the WordPress recognizable `front-page.php` since I'm trying to target the home (front) page.

`home-meta.php` (located in metaboxes in my theme folder)

```
    <?php
    
    /**
     * Home Page Custom Meta Content
     *
    **/
    
    function add_home_meta_box() {  
        add_meta_box(  
            'home_meta_box', // $id  
            'Home Page Content', // $title   
            'show_home_meta_box', // $callback  
            'page', // $page  
            'normal', // $context  
            'high'); // $priority
        add_meta_box(  
            'home_meta_box_lower_1', // $id  
            'Home Lower Left', // $title   
            'show_home_meta_box_lower_left', // $callback  
            'page', // $page  
            'normal', // $context  
            'high'); // $priority    
        add_meta_box(  
            'home_meta_box_lower_2', // $id  
            'Home Lower Center', // $title   
            'show_home_meta_box_lower_center', // $callback  
            'page', // $page  
            'normal', // $context  
            'high'); // $priority 
        add_meta_box(  
            'home_meta_box_lower_3', // $id  
            'Home Lower Right', // $title   
            'show_home_meta_box_lower_right', // $callback  
            'page', // $page  
            'normal', // $context  
            'high'); // $priority 
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_home_meta_box'); 
    
    
    // Creating Array for Fields
    $prefix = 'home_';
    $home_meta_fields = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H2 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Sub Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H3 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Caption',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Caption Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 1140px wide x 530px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        )
    );// end caption array
    
    $prefix2 = 'home_lower_left_';
    $home_meta_fields_lower_left = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Title',
            'desc' => 'H2 title for column.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Column Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 360px wide x 300px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix2.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Sub-Title',
            'desc' => 'H3 sub-title above text block.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Text block',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix2.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Label',
            'desc' => 'Button link label (what user reads on button).',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_label',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Title Tag',
            'desc' => 'On hover and SEO text.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_title_tag',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button URL',
            'desc' => 'URL where button links to. Enter http:// to work.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_url',
            'type' => 'text'
        )
    );// end lower left array
    
    $prefix3 = 'home_lower_center_';
    $home_meta_fields_lower_center = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Title',
            'desc' => 'H2 title for column.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Column Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 360px wide x 300px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix3.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Sub-Title',
            'desc' => 'H3 sub-title above text block.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Text block',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix3.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Label',
            'desc' => 'Button link label (what user reads on button).',
            'id' => $prefix3.'btn_label',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Title Tag',
            'desc' => 'On hover and SEO text.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'btn_title_tag',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button URL',
            'desc' => 'URL where button links to. Enter http:// to work.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'btn_url',
            'type' => 'text'
        )
    );// end lower center array
    
    $prefix4 = 'home_lower_right_';
    $home_meta_fields_lower_right = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Title',
            'desc' => 'H2 title for column.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Column Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 360px wide x 300px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix4.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Sub-Title',
            'desc' => 'H3 sub-title above text block.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Text block',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix4.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Label',
            'desc' => 'Button link label (what user reads on button).',
            'id' => $prefix4.'btn_label',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Title Tag',
            'desc' => 'On hover and SEO text.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'btn_title_tag',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button URL',
            'desc' => 'URL where button links to. Enter http:// to work.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'btn_url',
            'type' => 'text'
        )
    );// end lower right array
    
    
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box() {
    global $home_meta_fields, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
    
        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }
    
    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields;  
          
        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  
          
        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta');
    // end Upper Home Content
    
    // Lower Left
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box_lower_left() {
    global $home_meta_fields_lower_left, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_left_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
    
        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_left as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }
    
    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta_lower_left($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields_lower_left;  
          
        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_left_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  
          
        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_left as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta_lower_left');
    // end lower left
    
    // Lower Center Column
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box_lower_center() {
    global $home_meta_fields_lower_center, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_center_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
    
        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_center as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }
    
    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta_lower_center($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields_lower_center;  
          
        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_center_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  
          
        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_center as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta_lower_center');
    // end lower center
    
    // Lower Right Column
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box_lower_right() {
    global $home_meta_fields_lower_right, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_right_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
    
        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_right as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }
    
    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta_lower_right($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields_lower_right;  
          
        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_right_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  
          
        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_right as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta_lower_right');
    // end lower right
    
    ?>
```

When I save all that, I get the following errors in the admin backend:

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /Users/[my_mac_user]/Sites/[dev_directory]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/functions.php on line 354
>
> Warning: include(http://[site_url]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/metaboxes/home-main-home.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /Users/[my_mac_user]/Sites/[dev_directory]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/functions.php on line 354
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://[site_url]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/metaboxes/home-main-home.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php') in /Users/[my_mac_user]/Sites/[dev_directory]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/functions.php on line 354

Also, I'm now no longer hiding the content box with the template name change to `front-page.php`. Tried using the global object of $post to get `page_on_front` too, but that doesn't work, either.

Error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/amores/Sites/[dev_directory]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme/functions.php on line 328

Additional code failed attempt:

```
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_editor' );
    
    function hide_editor() {
        // Get the Post ID
        global $post;
        if ( $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
          remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
           
            // add custom .js to footer for uploading images
                function custom_admin_js() {
                $url = get_option('siteurl');
                $url = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/library/js/libs/meta-content.js';
                echo '"<script type="text/javascript" src="'. $url . '"></script>"';
                }
                add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js');
                
    //          include 'metaboxes/home-meta.php';
    
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to run into other problems, using the name `page-home.php`. Is this template for your **site front page**, or for your **blog posts index**?

Comment: Also: are you trying to load meta boxes on the **front end**, or in the **admin area**, in the **edit page** screen?

Comment: this is all for the admin area. will change the template to a different name

Comment: The solution to the underlying problem still depends on *what site page* you intend: the **site front page**, or the **blog posts index**?

Comment: @ChipBennett, it's the site's front page, i.e. the home page.

Comment: @ChipBennett, just letting you know I updated the original question with where I'm at now, in case that helps.

Comment: Please use `get_template_directory_uri()` rather than `TEMPLATEPATH`. Also, you'll need to include the code from `metaboxes/home-meta/php`, if you're getting errors in that code.

Comment: Also: you should rename your template as `front-page.php`, and remove any `Template Name: ` PHPdoc from the header. WordPress will use that template automatically. Don't query by `_wp_page_template`; rather, query via `get_option( 'page_on_front' )`.

Comment: Hey @ChipBennett, I updated the question with where I'm at with it currently. Thanks!

Comment: #facepalm. Silly mistake on my part. Use `get_template_directory()` (filepath) rather than `get_template_directory_uri()` (url path) inside of `include()`.

Comment: double-doh... forgot and included the old .php path... updated that and using the `get_template_directory` instead of the `_uri` call, but still getting an error.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/amores/Sites/[dev_directory]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/functions.php on line 328

Comment: What is on `line 328` of `functions.php`?

Comment: Line 328: `if ( $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {`

Comment: That's what I thought. I don't think the global `$post` object is available at `admin_init`. Try using a later action, such as `add_meta_boxes`?

Comment: Well, I'm finally able to hide the content area box on the page using `$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
 if($post_id == '104'){' but I'm still not getting any of the metaboxes to show up using the `home-meta.php` pasted above

Comment: Is the `home-meta.php` file being included properly? If so (which I assume, based on your earlier file-include error message), I would recommend starting a **new question** to address the issues specific to that functional file.

Comment: thanks @ChipBennett. posted a new question specifically related to that. thanks for your help! also, I found [this site for a metabox class](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/ "custom metabox class for wordpress") that you may find useful.

Comment: Don't forget either to accept one of the posted answers, or add your own answer to describe your solution, and then accept it, so that we can close out this question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment:

> @ChipBennett, it's the site's front page, i.e. the home page.

(Side note: in WordPress the *home* page is **not** the **Site Front Page**, but rather the **Blog Posts Index**. `is_home()` returns true on the *blog posts index*, and not necessarily on the *site front page*. This is important to understand, as it can make certain function names and terminology confusing.)

This is actually quite easy. If your **site front page** is a **static page**, then you can find out the ID of that page like so:

```
get_option( 'page_on_front' );
```

Next step: hook your metabox code into the correct hook: `'add_meta_boxes'`, or, more precisely: `'add_meta_boxes_page'`:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page','load_home_meta' );
function load_home_meta() {}
```

Next, I'll assume that all of your meta box definition code is in the functional file `/metaboxes/home-main-home.php`? We just want to load it only conditionally, which we'll do as follows:

```
global $post;
if ( $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
    // Load meta boxes file
}
```

Next, you need to reference that file properly. I'll assume we're working with a Theme? In that case, you need to reference `get_template_directory_uri()`:

```
include( get_template_directory() . '/metaboxes/home-main-home.php' );
```

Putting it all together:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page','load_home_meta' );
function load_home_meta() {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/metaboxes/home-main-home.php' );
    }
}
```

This all assumes, of course, that the functional code in `/metaboxes/home-main-home.php` is correct...

#### Edit

Use `get_template_directory()` (filepath) rather than `get_template_directory_uri()` (URL path) for `include()` calls.

Comment: thanks, @chip. I tried doing your approach but a blank/white screen...

Comment: Enable `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php`, and report the **fatal error**.

Comment: I would if it wasn't a white screen of death. :(

Comment: With `WP_DEBUG` enabled, you'll see a fatal error instead of the WSOD. :)

Comment: like this, `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` no? in `wp-config.php` it's set. still white screen.

Comment: In the document source as well?

Comment: which one, the, home-meta.php file?

Comment: in your browser, wherever you're getting the WSOD. View source on it. Do you see a fatal error?

Comment: There's nothing on source, either... Will edit the post above to show you what I have right now in functions and in metabox

Answer (score 0):

Use [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

So it will be like

```
if (is_front_page()) {
 include 'metaboxes/home-meta.php';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work:

    add_action('admin_init','load_home_meta');
    function load_home_meta() {
     if (is_front_page()) {
      include 'metaboxes/home-meta.php';
     }
    }

Only this works, but I don't want it globally:

    include 'metaboxes/home-meta.php';