# Custom metabox not working

Tags: custom-field, functions, metabox, include

Morning!

I have a call in my `functions.php` file to include a custom meta-box php file in my theme's directory called: `/metaboxes/home-meta.php`

The code is as follows for the call:

```
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page','load_home_meta' );
    function load_home_meta() {
        $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
        if($post_id == '104'){
            include( get_template_directory() . '/metaboxes/home-meta.php' );
        }
    }
```

The include is now working (had an `add_meta_boxes` function wrapped around my metaboxes within the `home-meta.php` file below (updated code)).

However, I'm getting errors in each metabox siting the first `case` within the `switch` for the callback functions. An example error is:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/[my_mac]/Sites/[site_dir]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/metaboxes/home-meta.php on line 224

The `home-meta.php` code is:

```
    <?php

    /**
     * Home Page Custom Meta Content
     *
    **/

add_meta_box(  
    'home_meta_box', // $id  
    'Home Page Content', // $title   
    'show_home_meta_box', // $callback  
    'page', // $page  
    'normal', // $context  
    'high'); // $priority
add_meta_box(  
    'home_meta_box_lower_1', // $id  
    'Home Lower Left', // $title   
    'show_home_meta_box_lower_left', // $callback  
    'page', // $page  
    'normal', // $context  
    'high'); // $priority    
add_meta_box(  
    'home_meta_box_lower_2', // $id  
    'Home Lower Center', // $title   
    'show_home_meta_box_lower_center', // $callback  
    'page', // $page  
    'normal', // $context  
    'high'); // $priority 
add_meta_box(  
    'home_meta_box_lower_3', // $id  
    'Home Lower Right', // $title   
    'show_home_meta_box_lower_right', // $callback  
    'page', // $page  
    'normal', // $context  
    'high'); // $priority 


    // Creating Array for Fields
    $prefix = 'home_';
    $home_meta_fields = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H2 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Sub Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H3 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Caption',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Caption Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 1140px wide x 530px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        )
    );// end caption array

    $prefix2 = 'home_lower_left_';
    $home_meta_fields_lower_left = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Title',
            'desc' => 'H2 title for column.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Column Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 360px wide x 300px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix2.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Sub-Title',
            'desc' => 'H3 sub-title above text block.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Text block',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix2.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Label',
            'desc' => 'Button link label (what user reads on button).',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_label',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Title Tag',
            'desc' => 'On hover and SEO text.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_title_tag',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button URL',
            'desc' => 'URL where button links to. Enter http:// to work.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_url',
            'type' => 'text'
        )
    );// end lower left array

    $prefix3 = 'home_lower_center_';
    $home_meta_fields_lower_center = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Title',
            'desc' => 'H2 title for column.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Column Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 360px wide x 300px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix3.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Sub-Title',
            'desc' => 'H3 sub-title above text block.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Text block',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix3.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Label',
            'desc' => 'Button link label (what user reads on button).',
            'id' => $prefix3.'btn_label',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Title Tag',
            'desc' => 'On hover and SEO text.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'btn_title_tag',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button URL',
            'desc' => 'URL where button links to. Enter http:// to work.',
            'id' => $prefix3.'btn_url',
            'type' => 'text'
        )
    );// end lower center array

    $prefix4 = 'home_lower_right_';
    $home_meta_fields_lower_right = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Title',
            'desc' => 'H2 title for column.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(  
            'label'  => 'Column Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 360px wide x 300px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix4.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Sub-Title',
            'desc' => 'H3 sub-title above text block.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Text block',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix4.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Label',
            'desc' => 'Button link label (what user reads on button).',
            'id' => $prefix4.'btn_label',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Title Tag',
            'desc' => 'On hover and SEO text.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'btn_title_tag',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button URL',
            'desc' => 'URL where button links to. Enter http:// to work.',
            'id' => $prefix4.'btn_url',
            'type' => 'text'
        )
    );// end lower right array


    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box() {
    global $home_meta_fields, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }

    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields;  

        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  

        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta');
    // end Upper Home Content

    // Lower Left
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box_lower_left() {
    global $home_meta_fields_lower_left, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_left_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_left as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }

    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta_lower_left($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields_lower_left;  

        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_left_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  

        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_left as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta_lower_left');
    // end lower left

    // Lower Center Column
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box_lower_center() {
    global $home_meta_fields_lower_center, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_center_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_center as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }

    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta_lower_center($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields_lower_center;  

        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_center_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  

        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_center as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta_lower_center');
    // end lower center

    // Lower Right Column
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box_lower_right() {
    global $home_meta_fields_lower_right, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_right_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_right as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }

    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta_lower_right($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields_lower_right;  

        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_right_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  

        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_right as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta_lower_right');
    // end lower right

    ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to include a meta box on the front end of the site?

Comment: No, these are edit-post screen metaboxes.

Comment: as @ChipBennett said, I'm trying to have the metaboxes show up in the admin area for editing a post/page. It seems that I'm not including the file properly, not sure where it's hanging.

Comment: So, the first step, before digging into all your metabox code: inside `home-meta.php`, can you create a very simple `add_meta_box()` call, and in the callback, just output some `HELLO WORLD` text?

Comment: *It seems that I'm not including the file properly, not sure where it's hanging* - Actually, [per your previous question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87682/how-to-load-php-file-for-specific-page-in-admin), you've verified that you're *including* the file properly. The problem is now with the *functional code itself*.

Comment: OK, I actually had to remove the function to add the metaboxes, now the boxes are showing up. But each metabox on the page is showing an error with each callback function. It's breaking at the first `case` within the switch. Posting the updated code above.

Comment: Great! So we've verified **1)** the `include()` is working as expected, and **2)** the `add_meta_box()` calls are working as expected. Now we just need to address the specific errors in the `add_meta_box()` callbacks.

Comment: Note on referencing code errors and line numbers: WPSE code doesn't add line numbers, so please explicitly identify the code on the line number referenced by any error. (In this case: `line 224`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem #1:

First problem: inside `home-meta.php`, pull all of your `add_meta_box()` calls **outside** of the `add_meta_boxes_home()` callback, and get rid of the callback and `add_action()` call. You handle this already, with the `add_meta_boxes_page` callback in `functions.php`, that includes `home-meta.php`.

### Problem #2:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/[my_mac]/Sites/[site_dir]/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/metaboxes/home-meta.php on line 224

Assuming that this is line 224:

```
foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {
```

I *think* the problem is that you globalize `$home_meta_fields` ***after* you define it**:

```
$home_meta_fields = array( ... );
```

...later followed by:

```
global $home_meta_fields, $post;
foreach ( $home_meta_fields as $field ) {
```

Try globalizing `$home_meta_fields` *before* you define it:

```
global $home_meta_fields;
$home_meta_fields = array( ... );
```

...then it should be recognized as a valid, set array in your `foreach()` call.

Comment: got that fixed and now the boxes are showing up properly, but still crashing on the switch

Comment: For the second problem, I believe you have a PHP syntax issue regarding when you *define* `$home_meta_fields` vs when you *globalize* `$home_meta_fields`. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @ChipBennet. That solved it! I globalized `$home_meta_fields` before the defined array and it's showing up properly. Thanks for the help and guidance!

Comment: Unfortunately, now when I click update, any new info entered into the meta boxes isn't being saved. Am I having the same globalize issue with the save functions? Error states: Notice: Undefined index: post in /nfs/c07/h04/mnt/111667/domains/staging.[site].org/html/wp-content/themes/[site_theme]/functions.php on line 329. `329` is `$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;` of the `hide_editor` function.